# Asymptotic behaviors of different types of equations with capillarity or viscous terms

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, soft-question

Let us consider
$$
\begin{align}
u_t + \left(\frac{u^2}{2}\right)_{\!\!x} = 0 \\
v_t + \left(\frac{v^2}{2}\right)_{\!\!x} - v_{xx} = 0 \\
\tilde v_t -\tilde v_{xx} = 0 \\
w_t + \left(\frac{w^2}{2}\right)_{\!\!x} - w_{xxx} = 0 \\
\tilde w_t - \tilde w_{xxx} = 0
\end{align}
$$

What are the different decay rates of
$$\|\cdot\|_{\infty}$$
for the solutions to these equations?

For the heat equation I know that
$\|\tilde v\|_{\infty} \sim t^{-1/2}$ and this asymptotic behavior is obtained by using the heat kernel. How about the others?